# Why does Ubuntu not allow keyboard shortcuts for snapping windows horizontally?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 19.10, window-manager, window-placement

In 19.10, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Mate and Xubuntu all have the ability to make a window occupy the upper half or the lower half of the screen using <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> respectively. But Ubuntu 19.10, out of the box, doesn't: instead, <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> maximize and restore windows.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason is mentioned in [Analyzing GNOME keyboard shortcuts](https://rabbitictranslator.com/wordpress/index.php/2019/10/14/analyzing-gnome-keyboard-shortcuts/) which is one in a series "to analyze keyboard shortcuts in most major DEs". Quoting from there:

> Meta+arrow does not match a full set of tiling like Plasma (in which Meta+Up/Down tiles up and down), that is, it does not match semantically, because GNOME acknowledges that tiling up and down is a waste of vertical space; instead, the more commonly-used maximize+restore is default.

The next paragraph in the article provides further argumentation citing linguistics and "how Up for maximize and Down for restore feel intuitive".

---

I briefly search for any official GNOME documentation justifying the use of <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to maximize and restore windows respectively but couldn't find any. [This](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/3.32/keyboard-input.html.en) classifies these shortcuts as "System reserved shortcuts" but doesn't provide any reasoning.